# How to display many2many field in kanban view ,without color label

Tags: opencv, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10, odoo-view

I have to try to display my field many2many in view kanban but don't work for me.
my field is
my code :**attribute_value_ids**

```
<templates>
           <t t-name="kanban-box">
           <div class="oe_kanban_global_click">
           <div class="oe_kanban_content">
           <field name="attribute_value_ids"/>
                     </div>
           <div class="o_kanban_image">
           <img t-att-src="kanban_image('product.product', 'image_small', 
               record.id.value)"/>
             </div>
             <div class="oe_kanban_details">
              <strong><field name="name"/></strong>
              <ul>
              <li>Price: <field name="lst_price"></field></li>
              </ul>
              <div name="tags"/>
                </div>
                </div>
                 </t>
                    </templates>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant, You have to install a custom addon which is available in odoo community